# Problems with the layout in my HTML code when using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am new in the front-end world and still learning a lot. I have a simple design and I am trying to convert it to HTML and CSS. Here is my simple design.

[image]

And this is my code so far:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #1d1c2d;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Ovo', serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row {
  max-width: 30%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #262438;
}

.formHolder {
  padding: 40px;
}

.row h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.search {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #262538;
  border: 1px solid #49485d;
  height: 69px;
  width: 100%;
}

::placeholder {
  padding-left: 45px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #8c8aa7;
}

input[type="text"] {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.btns {
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.input-icons i {
  position: absolute;
}

.input-icons {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.icon {
  color: #8c8aa7;
  top: 47%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.input-field {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn {
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #1d1c2d;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #8c8aa7;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #8780f8;
  color: #fff
}

.active {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #8780f8;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mulish:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Ovo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="formHolder">
        <h2>Review</h2>
        <div class="input-icons">
          <i class="fas fa-search icon"></i>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search reviews" class="search input-field">
        </div>

        <div class="btns">
          <button class="btn">Experience</button>
          <button class="btn">Quality</button>
          <button class="btn active">Design</button>
          <button class="btn">Size</button>
          <button class="btn">Features</button>
          <button class="btn">Value</button>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see in my code I have problems with widths, the layout is messed up, I don't know how to solve this, also these buttons go outside the div. I am using the Flexbox, can somebody try to help me with this? Or guide me in best practices of how to achieve this design to code. Thank you all. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need display:flex here. Simply use display:block for parent element and display: inline-block for the children.

```
<div class="input-icons" style="position: relative;">
          <i class="fas fa-search icon" style="top: 39%;"></i>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search reviews" class="search input-field">
        </div>

.btns {
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.btn {
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #1d1c2d;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #8c8aa7;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply give display: flex; and `flex-wrap: wrap;`  to your `.btns` class it will solve your problem OR you can give `display: block`

> what  flex-wrap with wrap  does Simply it will wrap all your stuff in your container
> **Note:**  flex-wrap will not work without display flex

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #1d1c2d;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Ovo', serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.row {
  max-width: 30%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #262438;
}

.formHolder {
  padding: 40px;
  border:2px solid yellow;
}

.row h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.search {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #262538;
  border: 1px solid #49485d;
  height: 69px;
  width: 100%;
}

::placeholder {
  padding-left: 45px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #8c8aa7;
}

input[type="text"] {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.btns {
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.input-icons i {
  position: absolute;
}

.input-icons {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.icon {
  color: #8c8aa7;
  top: 47%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.input-field {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn {
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #1d1c2d;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #8c8aa7;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #8780f8;
  color: #fff
}

.active {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #8780f8;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mulish:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Ovo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="formHolder">
        <h2>Review</h2>
        <div class="input-icons">
          <i class="fas fa-search icon"></i>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search reviews" class="search input-field">
        </div>

        <div class="btns">
          <button class="btn">Experience</button>
          <button class="btn">Quality</button>
          <button class="btn active">Design</button>
          <button class="btn">Size</button>
          <button class="btn">Features</button>
          <button class="btn">Value</button>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```